# Use own MSSQL Instace for TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2014

We have a single MS Server 2012 for hosting our MSSQL 2014.
On the Server we already installed two instances of MSSQL 2014.
One for the productive Business-Applications and one instance for the development Databases.

Beside the MSSQL 2014 installation we need to setup the TFS2013.

My question is if it is a good thought to make an own instance for the TFS or if we should just use one of the existing instances (Probably the dev) to store the databases.
We would love to use another instance because we would like to isolate the TFS Databases (so a restart of the TFS SQL Service should not affect the prod dbs) from the rest. We know that the administration needed for three instances is bigger than for two but we can neglect that.

Will there be a big loose in performance with a third instance, or isnt it that dramatic?

To avoid some anwsers, there is no possibility to implement the TFS or MSSQL on an other server(Because we just don't have any free resources).
The Server is from the hardware POV suitable and because we're a small company there won't be that much connections to the DB's (40 Employees to the Prod Instance, 3-5 Developers connecting to the DEV and TFS Instances).

Comment: *We would love to use another instance because we would like to isolate the TFS Databases from the rest.* Many databases on 1 SQL Server are isolated from one another... Unless you are lazy and give everybody `sysadmin`

Comment: Yes thats true, but with this I meant more that if the TFS service needs to be restarted it should not affect the prod dbs. I edited my question.

Comment: I don't think TFS needs you to restart SQL Server when it itself is restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data tier of your TFS installation does not require any restarts. It's just a database that's created on your SQL Server.

The application tier of TFS is where the real work happens. This is where your users connect to and where the Windows Service and IIS websites are running.

It is no problem to use a shared SQL Server instance for installing Team Foundation Server.

If you want more information on how to install TFS checkout the ALM Rangers documentation. We have just released a new version of the guide that can be found [here](http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/122171).

Comment: First of all I'm glad that I can say: "thank you very much" to one of the guys who created such a great documentation! Thank you for your work it was really helpful to me. But to come back to my problem, what kept me struggling was the Chapter "Real World Reference Stories" - Scenario 1, wich is an example for a Company named "Contoso Ltd". The starting Summary is written like it is wrong to host a TFS on a Server or at least in an instance with other Databases in it. So is this scenario telling me not to host a TFS in an Instance with other DB's ?

Comment: Scenario 1 mentions that it's possible from a technical point of view but it can result in maintenance problems. For example, if multiple applications use one single SQL Server installation, it it's harder to upgrade the machine if the applications have different requirements. I'm not a SQL Server expert but I wonder if having multiple instances on one machine allows you to upgrade them separately to avoid these issues. Since you have a small amount of users, you could choose to use the SQL Server standard license of TFS to install all components on one box.

Answer (score 1):

I would install also on a separate instance because the development or the production databases may require an SQL Server services restart which will cause a TFS unavailability.
Also you don't want to give permissions to the developers on TFS databases (usually developers are requiring higher permissions on their development databases, e.g. sysadmin for backup/restore)